# SSRS report returning error - The sort expression for the group 'grp' contains an error: Attempted to divide by zero

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, expression

I am attempting to fix an error in a previous developers SSRS report. There is a group by parameter, when choosing a certain value it returns the error - The sort expression for the grouping 'grp' contains an error: Attempted to divide by zero.

The error suggests this expression is causing the error;
=-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value)/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value)

Selecting other parameters works without any errors.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

I don't know what further information to provide but can if it specified.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is caused when the sum of `Fields!RentDue.Value` is zero.  To fix this, a simple `IIF` statement to check for zero should fix the issue.  Try the following expression.

```
=Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value)/IIF(Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, didn't work, I wonder if it's the expression that is being used in the group by for sorting, any more ideas?                             =choose(Parameters!sort.Value,
choose(Parameters!set.Value,Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value,Fields!ManagementArea.Value,Fields!RentGroup.Value,Fields!Tenure.Value),
-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp"),
Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp"),
-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp")/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp"))

Comment: @user3306489 `Choose` isn't a function in SSRS, so I'd say yes, that expression is your issue.

Comment: The expression works with some values but not with one parameter value. Is there anything you can suggest to rewrite the expression?

Comment: @user3306489 Since `choose` is not a function in SSRS, I can't really suggest anything as I don't know what the expression is doing.  I'd probably go with a switch, but I can't tell what the expected result is supposed to be.  If you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56223297/edit) some information on what that expression is meant to do into the question, I could give it another look.

Comment: Choose does appear under common functions -> Program flow. Is there a way to prevent it from returning null values?

Comment: Wow, that's strange.  I've never heard of it or seen it used.  I would recommend using a similar `IIF` in this part of the expression: `-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp")/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp")`.  The original error was division by zero and this is the only part that does division.